# Multi site migration error for wildcard domains

Tags: multisite

I have setup the wildcard domains. Domains are like:

```
subdomain-1.abc.com
subdomain-2.abc.com
```

Etc.

All works awesome. But, I have change the hosting and migrated my multisite. And the subdomains are broken. The subdomains are listed in the in database. It show the network admin page with all subdomain list but when I visit the subdomain it broke the website.

To fix this I have updated the .htaccess but it not works. Any suggestions?

Comment: While your DNS records (or at least, your local /etc/hosts DNS table) may point to the new hosting provider, have you configured the subdomains to resolve to the wordpress install's docroot as migrated to the new hosting server?  If you added the subdomains through CPanel on the new hosting provider with default settings, it would have created separate docroots for each subdomain's web files.  You can probably symlink them back to the main wordpress install folder, or just remap their docroots.

Comment: Hi Anson, Thanks for the suggestions. The issue is resolved. I have added (*) star as a sub domain name in the CPanel. And removed .Htaccess and everything works as expected.